# XBMC Standalone advancedsettings.xml path

Tags: path, kodi

I am using XBMC standalone (i.e.)

```
systemctl enable xbmc.service
```

I cannot figure out where to store the `advancedsettings.xml` file in this scenario. According to the [XBMC Wiki](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=HOW-TO:Modify_the_video_cache), it should be in `~/.xbmc/userdata/`. But that doesn't fit this scenario. Where should I store my `advancedsettings.xml` file?

Answer (score 0):

Check what is actually in your advancedsettings.xml file.

I may have had a similar problem using lightdm to autoboot into xbmc-standalone and it wasn't finding my MySQL server.

I fixed this by setting a static IP in /etc/network/interfaces and now when XBMC starts I get "Waiting for network configuration" and then connects to MySQL and shows my movies.